# Second network card appears fried. Why and how to prevent a third?

Tags: networking, power, hardware-failure, modem, openbsd

So I have an old computer functioning as an OpenBSD router for my home network. I had 3 network cards, one to wired home network, one to wireless network, and one to my modem. One day, pings magically stopped working. I login to the router with ssh over my wired network.. everything appears fine. dhclient is still getting an address from the modem and everything, but ping 8.8.8.8 doesn't work.. I double and triple checked my configuration for 2 days trying to figure out why.

Finally, I decide to try putting in another network card. I put it in and change everything from fxp0 to rl2 and everything magically works again..

Now fast forward to today. Today, my power went out from a thunderstorm. I had both my main computer(for some reason forgot to change it over) and router plugged into the modem. After the power came back on and the storm passed I powered the two machines back up. I could get internet on my computer plugged into the modem, but not on my router. Once again, dhcp works fine, but ping fails.

It appears that another network card got fried. I would blame the modem, but why didn't my home computer's network card also get fried? How can I prevent another one from getting fried?

Also, is there anyway to tell if the network card is actually fried?

Comment: Are you using HomeplugAV, or another powerline networking solution?

Answer (score 1):

Why?

Thunderstorm

How to prevent?

Surge protection, or a battery backup with quality surge protection

How to tell if it is fried?

try it in another pci slot or another PC.

Comment: Had surge protection :/

Comment: Surge protection on the ethernet cable?

Comment: If lightning hits my ethernet cables in my house, I have bigger problems than a fried NIC

Comment: Surge over ethernet is what kills most nic's